# CSS hold parent horizontal menu background

Tags: html, css

I am designing simple horizontal menu with `html/css`, see [jsfiddle.net](https://jsfiddle.net/zjzzsqtf/). The problem is that after hovering on `li` childrens i can not hold parent `li` background. See print screens below:

[image]

in this state, after hover on menu childrens, such as `Settings` or `Applications`, i can't hold background of parent block, such as `Options` :

[image]

Comment: demo - https://jsfiddle.net/victor_007/zjzzsqtf/1/ ? `.nav li:hover {
  background-color: #2e2e2e;
}`

Comment: @Vitorinofernandes yes :) which css style edited ?

Comment: @Vitorinofernandes why  answer  in  comments ( just curiousity )?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You had added `:hover` effect for `a` tag and when you leave the `a` tag `:hover` is lost you can just add `:hover` to `li` tag and the `:hover` by using this you will not loose the `:hover` effect of the parent

```css
.nav {
  background: #C2E2EC;
  height: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 0 10px 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.nav li {
  float: right;
  list-style-type: none;
  position: relative;
}
.nav li a {
  font-size: 11px;
  color: #000;
  display: block;
  line-height: 50px;
  padding: 0 26px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: Tahoma;
  text-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
}
/* changed :hover to li:hover */
.nav li:hover {
  background-color: #2e2e2e;
}
#settings img {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#settings a {
  height: 50px;
  font-size: 11px;
}
#settings img {
  width: 48px;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  font-size: 11px;
}
#search {
  width: 338px;
  margin: 4px;
}
#search_text {
  width: 297px;
  padding: 12px;
  font-size: 11px;
  font-family: tahoma;
  border: 0 none;
  height: 34px;
  direction: rtl;
  text-align: right;
  margin-right: 0;
  color: white;
  outline: none;
  background: #1f7f5c;
  float: right;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  transition: all 0.15s;
}
#search_text:focus {
  background: rgb(64, 151, 119);
}
#search_button {
  border: 0 none;
  cursor: pointer;
  float: left;
  height: 34px;
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
  width: 34px;
}
#options a {
  border-left: 0 none;
}
#options > a {
  background-position: 85% center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  padding-right: 42px;
  color: #fff;
}
.subnav {
  visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  top: 110%;
  right: 0;
  width: 200px;
  height: auto;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 0.1s;
  background: #232323;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.subnav li {
  float: none;
}
.subnav li a {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #2e2e2e;
  color: #fff;
}
#options:hover .subnav {
  visibility: visible;
  top: 100%;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<ul class="nav">
  <li id="options"><a href="#">Options</a>
    <ul class="subnav">
      <li><a href="#">Settings</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Application</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Board</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Options</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: It would be nice if you gave a thought to highlighting how your code is different and what you have done rather than just posting code as an answer

Comment: @Vitorino fernandes Thanks, whats opening submenu animation ?

Comment: `#options:hover .subnav {
  visibility: visible;
  top: 100%;
  opacity: 1;
}` @mahdipishguy

Comment: @Vitorinofernandes Thank you very much